# my Split() function return only NaN or null data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

first thank you for your time.

I need to make a cross between two Pandas dataframes with the values that I have in a field. The values come in the following form within a field: [A,B,C,N]

I am trying to apply a SPLIT() function to the dataframe field as follows:

`df_test = df_temp["NAME"].str.split(expand=True)`

The "Name" field is of type object.

My problem is that for some reason my split() splits the values of my NAME field with Null (NaN) values. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need separate rows for your `Name` column, which essentially would contain `A` `B` `C` `D` in each of its rows?

Comment: yes, and add those columns in the same dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the input -

Input data -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],), ], schema = ['Name'])
df.show()

+------------+
|        Name|
+------------+
|[A, B, C, D]|
+------------+
```

Required Output -

```
df.select(explode(col("Name")).alias("exploded_Name")).show()

+-------------+
|exploded_Name|
+-------------+
|            A|
|            B|
|            C|
|            D|
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a value to separate the column with.

```
df['Name'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but it returns Null values. Apparently the field takes it as a list or array, I must transform the entire field to string right?

Comment: I have tried what you say, but this method separates me into a new dataframe, and I need them to be in the same one. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post your dataframe structure? It helps me understand the problem better and to give a better explanation.